# Using Gulp to add a timestamp to filename

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp

Using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) I've got a pretty simple build process which compresses everything into `styles.min.css`

```
gulp.task( 'styles', function() {
    gulp.src( './scss/*.scss' )
    .pipe( sass( { errLogToConsole: true } ) )
    .pipe( autoprefix( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
    .pipe( cssmin() )
    .pipe( rename( 'styles.min.css' ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( '../dist' ) );
});
```

Can I modify this to append a timestamp to the file name, so my browser knows this is a new file and to clear its cache?

Something like this:

`styles—1423267988.min.css`

Comment: `rename( 'styles.min.css' )` <-- so just put a timestamp here

Comment: @zerkms Is there a way to automate that?

Comment: Yes, put a current timestamp there. There is a `Date` object in JS available.

Comment: `.pipe( rename( 'styles-'+((new Date()).getTime())+'.min.css' ) )` like so

Comment: I suggest posting an answer to your own question and marking it as accepted.

Comment: @DavidParlevliet I actually ended up with that exact code before giving gulp-rev a shot — which seems to be a cleaner approach. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Follow-up:**

Apparently, this is called *cache-busting* or *fingerprinting*

Using [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) will append a hash to your output file.

```
...
    .pipe( rev() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( '../dist' ) );
});
```

Comment: Correct, that would be a better solution, it saves cache busting for no reason